# How can I join two lists within a Cavas App?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I two tables with some common properties and I want to join them into a new list.

A simplified example:

```
Record List1Item(int Id, string Name)
Record List2Item(int Id, bool IsActive)
```

Desired output of the items in the result would be in this shape

```
record JoinedListItem(int Id, string Name, bool IsActive)
```

My use case is to display a list of people, using information for each person contained in two lists.
Joining the data before would prevent me having to repeatedly iterate the tables per record displayed.

Unfortunately I'm restricted to using just Power Apps due to budget restrictions.

So, I can't create a Logic App Workflow or an Azure Function as that would incurred costs on top of that flat rate we pay for Power Apps. Which is a shame, as a logic workflow would make it quite trivial.

Comment: I made an argument for budget in the end as the work involved to do such a simple operation added too much complication, would have become hard to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To join the second list into the first one you can use the [AddColumns function](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-table-shaping) to add the columns from the second list into the first one, using a [LookUp](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-filter-lookup) call to retrieve the data from the second table:

```
ClearCollect(
  List1,
  {Id: 1, Name: "John Doe"},
  {Id:2, Name: "Jane Roe"},
  {Id:3, Name: "Jim Poe"},
  {Id:4, Name:"Joan Coe"});
ClearCollect(
  List2,
  {Id:1, IsActive:true},
  {Id:3, IsActive:true},
  {Id:4, IsActive:false});
ClearCollect(
  JoinedList,
  AddColumns(
    List1 As L1,
    "IsActive",
    LookUp(List2, Id = L1.Id, IsActive)))
```

Notice in the example above the List2 doesn't have an item for Id=2, so the joined list will have a blank value. You can update the expression to change the blank value to something else, for example wrapping the LookUp call above with the [Coalesce function](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-isblank-isempty), as shown below:

```
Coalesce(LookUp(List2, Id = L1.Id, IsActive), false)
```

Another option is to use the [ForAll function](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-forall) to merge the tables, which would be better if there are many columns in the second list, using the [Patch function](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-patch#merge-records-outside-of-a-data-source) to merge the records between the two lists:

```
ClearCollect(
  JoinedList2,
  ForAll(
    List1 As L1,
    Patch(L1, LookUp(List2, Id = L1.Id))))
```

Like in the first example, the columns of any items from the second list that don't have a match in the first list would be blank.